# Helm chart, can values file anchor aliases be prefixed or suffixed?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

If I have a helm chart ***`values.yaml` file*** that has an anchor like this:

```yaml
topics:
  - name: &topic my-topic
```

Is there any way that I can *prepend* or *append* to the alias/reference and do something like this:

```yaml
topics:
  - name: &topic my-topic
subscriptions:
  - name *topic-subscription
```

So that the name of the subscription becomes `my-topic-subscription`?

I know that I cannot do what I show above, I have tried the following, and none of them had any success:

- `subscription-*topic`
- `*topic-subscription`
- `'*topic-subscription'`
- `'*topic'-subscription`
- `"*topic-subscription"`
- `"*topic"-subscription`

Then I ran out of other ideas to try.

In the [official documentation](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/), I could not find any examples showing what I'm trying to do, but I also couldn't find anything saying that it cannot be done.

Comment: You can't use YAML anchors this way.  If you use an anchor, then one place in the YAML tree contains exactly the same content as another, and you cannot change the text or append a string or anything else.  [Helm values.yaml: Use Anchors in multiline string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73538649/helm-values-yaml-use-anchors-in-multiline-string) covers somewhat similar ground.  Since you do have the Helm/Go-template engine available, using that and constructing values in your chart's template code might work better.